# writing code - a compare function with two values

Tags: python

I need to write a program that takes two values `x` and `y` and returns

```
 1 if x >  y
 0 if x == y
-1 if x <  y
```

I cannot figure out how to start this. I know how to do one value, but not sure where to add the second.

Comment: Do you know about `elif` and `else`? See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comment: Hi Blair, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, in its current form, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I understand your having problems, but your question is quite broad. If your new to Python and having trouble getting started, consider search the web for a tutorial such as [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). If you have a _specific_ problem while programing, feel free to post a question here, but before posting again, please take the [tour], visit the [help], and make sure your question hasn't already been asked.

Comment: Okay sorry about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def func (x, y):
    if x>y:
        return 1
    elif x==y:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

To get return:

```
output=func(4, 6)
```

Or whatever

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that are off-topic. It sends a confusing message to the OP and others about Stack Overflow's quality standards. Please see [_How do I write a good answer?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)